# Proxy every instance in Guice for testing

Tags: java, proxy, mocking, mockito, guice

Is there a way to proxy every instance right after it's initialisation so that the proxy is being injected further?

Here's the regular approach to fully mocked classes:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(
            new AbstractModule() {
                @Override
                protected void configure() {
                    bind(EntityManager.class).toInstance(mock(EntityManager.class));
                }
            }
    );
}
```

What I would need to create would be:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(
            new AbstractModule() {
                @Override
                protected void configure() {
                    proxy(c -> c.equals(SomeService.class)) // matcher or class for classes that should be proxied with the function below
                                .with(o -> Mockito.spy(o)); // function to proxy the instances with mockito spying 
                }
            }
    );
}
```

I would later expect SomeService instance that I get from injector to be a proxy and all it's dependencies to be proxies as well.

Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Comment: You usually don't need to use Guice in your tests unless you test your modules. Don't test what you didn't write: test only what you wrote. So leave Guice out of your tests.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, but it's actually about integration test between different modules/services that in reality communicate with different APIs. That's why it's important to be able to mock a lot of services, but I also don't want to build them myself - it would take around 100 lines of code per test class :'(

Comment: I did just a couple of search online and could come up with an answer, already on this website. So please look at the other question's answer, it will answer this question too.